# Feasible way to grey out the close button at the upper right corner of Console Window?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw

I use GCC--mingw32 to compile a program on Windows.
Are there some feasible ways to grey out the close button at the upper right corner of "Console Window"? (like adding some codes?)

I don't want to close my program incautiously XDD

I tried something like this, but never works, help me, thanks.

```
HWND StdHandle = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
HMENU SystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(StdHandle, FALSE);
EnableMenuItem(SystemMenu, 0, MF_GRAYED);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
W := GetConsoleWindow; // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
M := GetSystemMenu(W, False);
//EnableMenuItem(M, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND or MF_DISABLED or MF_GRAYED);
DeleteMenu(M, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It works. I added a C style code (which meets my need) for someone who will see this post in the future.