# How to disable the `Close` item of console window context menu?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Windows 7
How to disable the `Close` item of console window context menu?

### UPD

I use PInvoke from C#:

```
const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
const uint MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;
const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
const uint MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint itemId, uint uEnable);

...

// Disable the close button and "Close" context menu item of the Console window
IntPtr hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
IntPtr hmenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false);
uint hWindow = EnableMenuItem(hmenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
```

My code disables "X" button, but "Close" item is still enabled and can be launched:

[image]

Comment: GetSystemMenu then DeleteMenu with the identifier for CLOSE

Comment: @AlexK.: That completely removes the menu entry. [EnableMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647636.aspx) can be used to disable a menu item.

Comment: Why would you want to remove this option? Seems kind of suspicious...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026461/feasible-way-to-grey-out-the-close-button-at-the-upper-right-corner-of-console-w/20028449#20028449

Comment: @DenisAnisimov, your variant is good too and works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SC_CLOSE` is the respective identifier to disable. `EnableMenuItem` disables X button and the menu item, however it appears that the trick does not work (older OSes?). Deletion of the menu item does work, including X box (non-client area handler presumably cannot check state of the menu item and applies disabled state; whereas disabled menu item is re-enabled and becomes available again).

```
const HMENU hMenu = GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE);
//EnableMenuItem(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
DeleteMenu(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

[image]

Comment: This code disables "X" button, but "Close" item is still enabled and can be launched.

Comment: I use pinvoke in C#. Maybe I set wrong values for `MF_BYCOMMAND`, `SC_CLOSE`  and `MF_DISABLED`?  I use such values: `const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
const uint MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002; const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;` Is it correct?

Comment: `MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED` is `0 | 0x02 | 0x01`. Disabled flag does not force graying out implicitly.

Comment: Yes, I use the same values, but "Close" context menu item is enabled still.

Comment: I added UPD in my theme.

Comment: Worked well with Windows 10, but indeed did not work with Windows Server 2003.

Comment: This is normal/usual way to disable closing, however implementation of console windows is different between OS versions (in other aspects, not necessarily regarding closing specifically) and my guess is that something re-enables the ability to get closed, even though the code is clear to keep closing disabled; fixed at some state and the problem is not present in latest OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
HWND hwndConsole = ::GetConsoleWindow();
HMENU hMenu = ::GetSystemMenu(hwndConsole, FALSE);
::DeleteMenu(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote a class library called librs you can download it on https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/librs_dll.html or http://plweb.pluginweb.ml/viewpage/librs.dll and you can write it `librs.menucontrol.DisableAll();` has update.